# Custom Design/Layout for Simple Products

Tags: css, php, bundled-product, grouped-products

I’m trying to customize simple products separate from grouped products. I’ve gone as far as creating a layout in `catalog.xml` with this code below

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple translate="label" module="catalog">
    <label>Catalog Product View (Simple)</label>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_type_simple" name="product.info.simple" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/simple.phtml">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.simple.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
                <label>Product Extra Info</label>
            </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
```

The code in `simple.phtml` is just an echo “hello” just to test it out to see if it’s adding that simple output. But I have no luck. Any steps I’m missing? I’ve also added code to `view.phtml` with this

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.info.simple'); ?>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you put in catalog.xml?

Answer (score 3):

When setting a template for an existing block, don't recreate the block with

```
<block type=…
```

Instead reference the existing block with its name and set the template variable

```
<reference name="product.info.simple">
      <action method="setTemplate"><file>path/to/template.phtml</file></action>
</reference>
```

plus: what Tim said :-) -> local.xml in your *package/theme/layout* folder!

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any reason why you need to change the template of `product.info.simple` block.

Magento uses different templates for `simple` and `grouped` products by default. Just copy `catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` template into your theme and modify it.

P.S.: Please don't modify `catalog.xml` but use `local.xml` instead.